Set a global variable's value from external sources Power Virtual Agent (Power Platform) Copilot Studio
I tried a lot of different way to apply this section "Set a global variable's value from external sources
" in this MS Docs but I can't get any useful info this screenshot of result  and I need to know how get BOT_ID from web.powerva.microsoft.com , I tried to get it from Token Endpoint
and from
https://web.powerva.microsoft.com/environments/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/bots/yyy-yyy-yyyy-yyy
I tried to use yyy-yyy-yyyy-yyy GUID but it also get this msg 
I only need to get Chatbot from Copilot studio and embedded it into .NET MAUI app and pass Username is a pre variable when chatbot start to know which user he talks with.
Tried steps in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-copilot-studio/authoring-variables-bot?tabs=webApp&source=docs
but not worked with me
